# How to ignore or pass xpath xml IndexError in Python

Tags: python, xml, lxml

How can I force python to ignore `IndexError` without using `try` & `except` every single value that I am extracting?

My XML have multiple values that needed to be extracted. Some records don't have the  value / at root[0], so I have to manually use `try` & `except IndexError:` for every single node that I am extracting.

Here's my code:

```
try:
    a = etree.XPath('/Data/a/b/nodeA/text()')(root)[0]  
except IndexError:  
    a = ''
try:
    b = etree.XPath('/Data/a/b/x/y/nodeB/text()')(root)[0]  
except IndexError:  
    b = ''
try:
    c = etree.XPath('/Data/a/b/d/nodeB/text()')(root)[0]  
except IndexError:  
    c = ''
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I use xpath queries I try to use looping instead of indexing. That way if the query doesn't find anything, the code nested in the loop never runs and you don'
t have to index because the loop values get bound to a local name in each iteration. Permit an example.

```
for a, b, c in zip(
    etree.XPath('/Data/a/b/nodeA/text()')
    etree.XPath('/Data/a/b/x/y/nodeB/text()')
    etree.XPath('/Data/a/b/d/nodeB/text()')):

    print a, b, c
```

Answer (score 1):

Test for the return value *before* trying to retrieve the first match:

```
a = etree.XPath('/Data/a/b/nodeA/text()')(root)
if a:
   # do something with a[0]
```

Alternatively, set `a` to an empty string or the first value on a single line:

```
a = etree.XPath('/Data/a/b/nodeA/text()')(root)
a = a[0] if a else ''
```